# Regular expression which 3 characters or more, min one minus, max 3 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the following regular expression:

- Must have 3 alphabetic caracters or more.
- Must have one lower case or more
- Can have 0 to 3 numbers (max 3) `0-9` (123 for example is 3 numbers)
- Must have exactly one `ú` (One `ú` exactly)
- Must finish with one of the following characters : `# } .`
- Must have min 9 chars, max 12

I try the following regular expression:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z]{3,})(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=.*[0-9]\d{0,3})(u{1})[A-Za-z0-9\d]{9,12}$/
```

One example valid: `aA2ca13ú}`

Comment: Can you please provide some examples which must fit and some which should not fit? "Must have 3 alphabetic characters" and "must have exactly one caracter" dont go well with each other.

Comment: For `Can have 0 to 3 numbers` where can these numbers be? All together in sequence or they can be split apart?

Comment: Edited, maybe you could understand now better

Comment: Does the one required `u` count as one of the 3 required alphabetical characters?

Comment: `^(?=.+(?:[A-Za-z].*){3,})(?=.+(?:-.*)+)(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){0,3}\D*$)(?=[^u]*u[^u]*$)(?=.{9,12}$).*[#}\.]$`

Comment: I change, now is ú

Comment: Can explain Ulugbek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex that should meet your requirements,

```
^(?=[^A-Za-z]*(?:[A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z]*){3,})(?=\D*\d?\D*\d?\D*\d?\D*$)(?=[^ú]*ú[^ú]*$)[úa-zA-Z\d-]{8,11}[#}.]$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lkg0Sh/2)**

Let me know if any of your case fails.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i edit expression regular cause you forgot the one minus min and remove the (?=[^-]*-) because i don't need to filter ^- ...
^(?=.*[A-Za-z]{3,})(?=.*[a-z]{1,})(?=\D*\d{0,3}\D*$)(?=[^ú]*ú[^ú]*$)[úa-zA-Z\d-]{8,11}[#}.]$

Comment: But also don't work in the case where number are a part for example:
ab2cú-12d.

Comment: But i don't need to have one hyphen:
One example valid should be:
aA2ca13ú}

Comment: The characters can or not be together, but at least must be 3 in all string

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, when i said minus i refere a-z (lowercase now)

Comment: I think you can understand better with this valid example : `aA2ca13ú}`

Comment: @JordiCastillo: I've updated my answer to support alphabets anywhere and minimum three and removed look ahead for hyphen presence. Please check.

Comment: Good job, honored!

Comment: @JordiCastillo: Glad I could help :)